# Select box in form blade Laravel

Tags: laravel, drop-down-menu, laravel-blade

how can I create a select box which is filled with values from the db?
The view is published with the $groups variable. In my select box i need $groups->id (hidden, only for storing) and $groups->name. This is currently my form.

```
{!! Form::open(array('route'=>'store.invitation')) !!} 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{Form::label('username', 'Username')}}
                        {{Form::text('username', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter Username'])}}

                        {{Form::label('groupname', 'Gruppe')}}
                        {{Form::select($groups->name) }}
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {{Form::submit('Submit',['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-close" href="{{ route('home') }}">Cancel</a>
                    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried to foreach your form::select?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an array of the data that you get from the db. Like this:

```
Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'));
```

This [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists) might be old, but thats how you can create Form::select in blade.